# Google Map Example Code (Australian map) Gives 2 Script Errors

Tags: javascript, html

When I run the Google code, I get two script errors.

1. Script error - https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default (no location or error type specified
2. http://www.ecars7255.com/FrontPageLinks/NetManagement/Mapping/GoogleMaps/MapContacts4pt6.html (specifies Line 21, Char 16, Syntax error type)

The Google code (HTML, CSS, and js modules) are published on our club website which is hosted by Go Daddy.

The HTML code is

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--
 @license
 Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
 SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
-->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Add Map</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" />
    <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <!--The div element for the map -->
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- prettier-ignore -->
    <script>(g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",c="google",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b[c]||(b[c]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback",c+".maps."+q);a.src=`https:maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})
        ({key: "***My API Key***", v: "beta"});</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The CSS code is

```css
/* 
 * Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element
 * that contains the map. 
 */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* 
 * Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. 
 */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

The JS code is

```js
// Initialize and add the map
let map;

async function initMap() {
  // The location of Uluru
  const position = { lat: -25.344, lng: 131.031 };
  // Request needed libraries.
  //@ts-ignore
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
  const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");

  // The map, centered at Uluru
  map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: position,
    mapId: "***my map ID***",
  });

  // The marker, positioned at Uluru
  const marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
    map: map,
    position: position,
    title: "Uluru",
  });
}

initMap();
```

```js
// Initialize and add the map
let map;

async function initMap() {
  // The location of Uluru
  const position = {
    lat: -25.344,
    lng: 131.031
  };
  // Request needed libraries.
  //@ts-ignore
  const {
    Map
  } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
  const {
    AdvancedMarkerElement
  } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");

  // The map, centered at Uluru
  map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: position,
    mapId: "***my map ID***",
  });

  // The marker, positioned at Uluru
  const marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
    map: map,
    position: position,
    title: "Uluru",
  });
}

initMap();
```

```css
/* 
 * Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element
 * that contains the map. 
 */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* 
 * Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. 
 */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
<h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
<!--The div element for the map -->
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
  (g => {
    var h, a, k, p = "The Google Maps JavaScript API",
      c = "google",
      l = "importLibrary",
      q = "__ib__",
      m = document,
      b = window;
    b = b[c] || (b[c] = {});
    var d = b.maps || (b.maps = {}),
      r = new Set,
      e = new URLSearchParams,
      u = () => h || (h = new Promise(async(f, n) => {
        await (a = m.createElement("script"));
        e.set("libraries", [...r] + "");
        for (k in g) e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g, t => "_" + t[0].toLowerCase()), g[k]);
        e.set("callback", c + ".maps." + q);
        a.src = `https:maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?` + e;
        d[q] = f;
        a.onerror = () => h = n(Error(p + " could not load."));
        a.nonce = m.querySelector("script[nonce]") ? .nonce || "";
        m.head.append(a)
      }));
    d[l] ? console.warn(p + " only loads once. Ignoring:", g) : d[l] = (f, ...n) => r.add(f) && u().then(() => d[l](f, ...n))
  })
  ({
    key: "***My API Key***",
    v: "beta"
  });
</script>
```

My program is registered in Google as ECARS Mod Logger. I have a funding source specified, an API key and a map ID. I have no other Google 'authorizations'.

It's very frustrating to not be able to get this simplest of programs to run. For several years, I had the Google maps running from this website but that ceased to function about a year to a year and a half ago when Google changed something fundamental in their programming approach. I have only just now gotten around to trying to reprogram to the new requirements.

Any help is appreciated.

I have been trying for the past 3 days (8/8 - 8/11). The expectations were to see the map of Australia as shown in the programming example.  Actual results are shown above

Answer (score 0):

What I've found in the provided code is you have
`https:maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`

which should be
`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?` (note // after https:)

```js
// Initialize and add the map
let map;

async function initMap() {
  // The location of Uluru
  const position = { lat: -25.344, lng: 131.031 };
  // Request needed libraries.
  //@ts-ignore
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
  const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");

  // The map, centered at Uluru
  map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: position,
    mapId: "***my map ID***",
  });

  // The marker, positioned at Uluru
  const marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
    map: map,
    position: position,
    title: "Uluru",
  });
}

initMap();
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}


html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* ignore the following */
.as-console-wrapper {display:none !important}
```

```html
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script> 


    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <!--The div element for the map -->
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- prettier-ignore -->
    <script>(g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",c="google",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b[c]||(b[c]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback",c+".maps."+q);a.src=`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})
        ({key: "", v: "beta"});</script>
```